# How this AbstractList returns List of Integer Objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

While going through the Effective Java examples, I failed to understand below code.
How this anonymous Abstract class return List of objects without iterating through array elements or calling the add() method.

what's going on behind the scenes in below code?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    List<Integer> list = intArrayAsList(a);
    System.out.println(list);
}

static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return a[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return a.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
            int oldVal = a[index];
            a[index] = element;
            return oldVal;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason *add* wasn't called is because it never created a new list. The new *AbstractList* is just holding a reference to the array 'a' and when you iterate over your new AbstractList, it will simply lookup in the array.

For fun, try to remove the keyword 'final' from that line:

```
static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) {
```

It will not compile anymore. The reason is because the AbstractList is an anonymous class and in order to be able to use a variable, that variable needs to be final.

Comment: Thanks Henri. And one correction is, only final fields are accessible inside anonymous inner classes irrespective of AbstractList.

Answer (score 1):

`new AbstractList<Integer>() { ... }` is not an abstract class. It is a subclass of the abstract type `AbstractList<Integer>`. That particular type implements almost all `List<Integer>` methods in terms of just two abstract methods: `get` and `set` (`size` is also needed for some operations), whose implementation is provided by your example.

In particular, there was no need to call the `add` method because the provided implementation is a closure wrapping the supplied `int[]`. The `AbstractList`'s implementation of `iterator()` will internally delegate to the provided implementation of `get`.

Comment: I have one more doubt like how the iterator() will be invoked. I saw the constructor in AbstractList is not calling any method. It would be helpful if you provide some references. Thanks.

Comment: Your code involves the iterator in the `toString()` method.

Comment: Right, the System.out.println will call the toString() method of AbstractList which is defined in AbstractCollection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29